# Freeswitch High availability

Tags: aws, voip, sip, high-availability

I have installed and configured FreeSwitch. It is up and running perfectly. Now I need to achieve high availability. My freeswitch was deployed in aws ubuntu ec2. As per aws docs for HA, it shows the floating ip concept. I tried this but I cant create a virtual ip in aws. I also tried efs. It also fails. Is there any other possible solutions?..

Comment: There are several answers already on - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72816019/high-availability-in-freeswitch